# Fetchinng Data from PHP REST API in flutter gives exception

Tags: php, android, json, flutter, rest

Created a REST API for fetching data in PHP MYSQL. Some of the data is fetched and other images are not fetched with the following message in exception.

Link to the REST API is https://gujapp.geekconnects.co/getdata.php .

After one use of app IP is blocked on any network. I have tried using VPN, but after some time it is also blocked.

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following SocketException was thrown resolving an image codec:
OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 104, address = gujapp.geekconnects.co, port = 59798

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
Image provider: NetworkImage("https://gujapp.geekconnects.co/parentuploads/images2.png", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://gujapp.geekconnects.co/parentuploads/images2.png", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

Code for the REST service

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'album.dart';


class Services {
  static var url = Uri.parse("https://gujapp.geekconnects.co/getdata.php");
  static Future<List<Album>> getPhotos() async{
    try{
      final response = await http.get(url);
      if(response.statusCode==200)
      {
        List<Album> list=parsePhotos(response.body);
        return list;
      }
      else
      {
        throw Exception("Erroor");
      }
    }catch(e){
      throw new Exception(e.toString());
    }
  }

  static List<Album> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<Album>((json)=>Album.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

}
```

Album.dart

```
class Album{
  String albumId;
  String id;
  String title;
  String url;
  String thumbnailUrl;

  Album({this.albumId,this.id,this.title,this.url,this.thumbnailUrl});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>json)
  {
    return Album(
      albumId: json['albumId'] as String,
      id: json['id'] as String,
      title: json['title'] as String,
      url: json['url'] as String,
      thumbnailUrl: json['thumbnailUrl'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

gridcell.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'album.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class AlbumCell extends StatelessWidget{
  const AlbumCell(this.album);
  @required
  final Album album;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                    placeholder: "images/no_image.png",
                    image: album.thumbnailUrl,
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4.0,10.0,4.0,10.0),
                child: Text(
                  album.title,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  softWrap: true,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(textStyle:TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your data class - `Album`

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Album {
  String albumId;
  String id;
  String title;
  String url;
  String thumbnailUrl;
  
  Album({
    required this.albumId,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.url,
    required this.thumbnailUrl,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'albumId': albumId,
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
      'url': url,
      'thumbnailUrl': thumbnailUrl,
    };
  }

  factory Album.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Album(
      albumId: map['albumId'],
      id: map['id'],
      title: map['title'],
      url: map['url'],
      thumbnailUrl: map['thumbnailUrl'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Album.fromJson(String source) => Album.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

And convert the data like this

```
Future<List<Album>> getAlbums() async {
var url = Uri.parse("https://gujapp.geekconnects.co/getdata.php");

try {
  final response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final maps = jsonDecode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Album.fromMap(maps[i]);
    });
  } else {
    throw Exception("Erroor");
   }
 } catch (e) {
  throw new Exception(e.toString());
 }
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            var albums = await getAlbums();
          },
          child: Text("Run"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Still not working I think it is the issue of my Hosting Provider. I am using a shared hosting CPanel.

Comment: It is impossible to understand where the error is without seeing the code in full. Remove all images from the project completely, and try adding images from a remote server